# Java Sockets sending multiple objects to the same server

Tags: java, sockets, object, server

I'm trying to send multiple Objects through a socket to a java server.

To have a gerneral type I convert my messages into an instance of the class Message and send this object to the server.
I wrote a little testclass, which sends three objects to the server. 
The problem is, only one objects reaches the server.
I tried nearly everything, without success.

My Server:

```
public class Server {
    private ServerConfig conf = new ServerConfig();
    private int port = Integer.parseInt(conf.loadProp("ServerPort"));
    Logger log = new Logger();
    ServerSocket socket;
    Chat chat = new Chat();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server s = new Server();
        if (s.runServer()) {
            s.listenToClients();
        }
    }

    public boolean runServer() {
        try {
            socket = new ServerSocket(port);
            logToConsole("Server wurde gestartet!");
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logToConsole("Server konnte nicht gestartet werden!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void listenToClients() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket client = socket.accept();
                ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new Handler(client, writer));
                clientThread.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void logToConsole(String message) {
        System.out.print(message);
    }

    public class Handler implements Runnable {

        Socket client;
        ObjectInputStream reader;
        ObjectOutputStream writer;
        User user;

        public Handler(Socket client, ObjectOutputStream writer) {
            try {
                this.client = client;
                this.writer = writer;
                this.reader = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                this.user = new User();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                Message incomming;
                try {
                    while ((incomming = (Message) reader.readUnshared()) != null) {
                        logToConsole("Vom Client: \n" + reader.readObject().toString() + "\n");
                        logToConsole(
                                "Vom Client: \n" + incomming.getType() + "-----" + incomming.getValue().toString());
                        handle(incomming);
                    }
                } catch (SocketException se) {
                    se.printStackTrace();
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

                }

            }
        }

        private void handle(Message m) throws IOException {
            String type = m.getType();
            if (type.equals(config.ConstantList.Network.CHAT.toString())) {
                chat.sendMessage(m);
            } else if (type.equals(config.ConstantList.Network.LOGIN.toString())) {
                System.out.println(user.login(m.getValue().get(0), writer));
                System.out.println(m.getValue().get(0));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The Client:

```
public class Connect {

    Socket client = null;
    ObjectOutputStream writer = null;
    ObjectInputStream reader = null;
    private Config conf = new Config();
    //private String host = conf.loadProp("ServerIP");
    String  host = "localhost";
    private int port = Integer.parseInt(conf.loadProp("ServerPort"));

    public boolean connectToServer() {
        try {
            client = new Socket(host, port);
            reader = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            writer = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            logMessages("Netzwerkverbindung hergestellt");
            Thread t = new Thread(new MessagesFromServerListener());
            t.start();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logMessages("Netzwerkverbindung konnte nicht hergestellt werden");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isConnectionActive() {
        if (client == null || writer == null || reader == null){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void sendToServer(Message m) {
        try {
            writer.reset();
            writer.writeUnshared(m);
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

And I try to send the objects with the class:

```
public void sendChatMessage(String username, String message) throws InterruptedException {
        ChatMessage cm = new ChatMessage();
        cm.setChat(username, null, message);
        Message m = new Message(cm);
        conn.sendToServer(m);
        System.out.println("SENDED");
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String username = "testuser";
        String chatmessage = "Hallo Welt!";
        connect.connect();
        sendChatMessage(username, chatmessage);
        sendChatMessage(username, chatmessage);
       sendChatMessage(username, chatmessage);
    }
```

I know that this is always the same message, but it is only for test purposes.
The messages are the objects they are Serializable and with only one object it works as designed.

Does anyone can see where I made my mistake?

Comment: Add a breakpoint in your server in the Handler where you expect your second Object to be read. Then step through the sources and see what's going on.

Comment: I did it, and here was only the one message shown, when the handling was finished, the server stayed idle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ((incomming = (Message) reader.readUnshared()) != null) {
```

Here you are reading an object, and blocking until it arrives.

```
    logToConsole("Vom Client: \n" + reader.readObject().toString() + "\n");
```

Here you are reading *another* object, and blocking till it arrives, and then erroneously logging it as the object you already read in the previous line.

Instead of logging `reader.readObject()`, you should be logging the value of `incoming`, which you have also misspelt.

And the loop is incorrect. `readObject()` doesn't return null at end of stream: it throws `EOFException`. It can return null any time you write null, so using it as a loop termination condition is completely wrong. You should catch `EOFException` and break.

Answer (score -2):

Found the solution, the line `logToConsole("Vom Client: \n" + reader.readObject().toString() + "\n");` in the Server class, blocks the connection.